# Create SharePoint Document Set URL dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have created custom content type, inherited it from Document Set parent content type and attached it to document library on SharePoint 2013 in Office 365.
Now i want to dynamically create URL to add new document set to that document library.

New (decoded) document set URL is : 
https://someSiteName/sites/siteName/_layouts/15/NewDocSet.aspx?List=ecc261fd-bedc-4ca7-acaa-e9af6f9aa27b&ContentTypeId=0x0120D52000DC8614ED8780EC4099731DA643B72155
00690255D5A1270C44B9C372797D0606EF&RootFolder=/sites/siteName/Certifications

If we observe query string parameters,
List = ListID,
ContentTypeId = ID of my custom content type,
RootFolder = Where document set is to be created

I have an issue getting ContentTypeId,
ContentTypeId=0x0120D52000DC8614ED8780EC4099731DA643B72155
**00690255D5A1270C44B9C372797D0606EF**
I am unable to find the highlighted part of GUID.
I can only find ContentTypeId=0x0120D52000DC8614ED8780EC4099731DA643B72155 from the URL when i navigate to SiteSettings > SiteContentType > Click on custom document set content type.

Answer (score 0):

It is the id of content type in document library. You can get it like below.

```
/_api/web/lists(listid)/contenttypes
```